# Assistance to understand the Microsoft's Inventory Database model

Tags: sql-server, database-design

checking the Database Model of the Northwind Database I could not understand the relationships of the [Inventory Transactions].
Mainly this table will store In and out transactions based on [Purchase Order ID] and [Customer Order ID].
I'm lost regarding the transaction of the product itself. I mean, there is a relationship with the Products table by [Product ID]. In my understanding it will work to manage the product OUTPUTS.
So why the table Purchase Order Details has a relationship with Inventory Transaction table by its [Inventory ID] ? If it is correct, why the Order Details table is not following the same concept even with the fields available in the table?

If someone can explain this model. Or perhaps have a better approach.
thanks in advance.

[image: Northwind_Inventory_DataModel]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question could only be answered by the developer of the database design (aka Microsoft). The community could possibly make some well educated guesses as to why it was developed the way it was, but a guess is only a guess. Depending on the business requirements or the programming language the database design can vary strongly. If you could be more specific with your question then you might receive an answer.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your feedbacks but how to be more specific than that? For instance, its about inventory database design, such approach is really relevant for that type of data transactions? If not, what would be a better one? Use as a foreign key on Order details table? I'm really in doubt if I can reproduce this same design approach or something else. I'm not a pro that's why I came here kindly asking for help and assistance of you guys that probably had face similar problem and can advise me on my pathway of learning and understanding.